# How to prove this inequality with this condition?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Let $A$ be the following matrix

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & x \\
0 & 1 & y \\
x & y & 1 
\end{array}
\right)$$

I have to prove that if, at least $x+y>\frac{3}{2}$, $A$ is not positive definite.

I have tried to prove it by calculating the eigenvalues, obtaining:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\lambda_1=1\\
\lambda_2=1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \\
\lambda_3=1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
\end{array}
$$

It is obvious that $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are always positive, so I only have to take care of $\lambda_3$. The problem is that I cannot relate the given condition with $1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<0$, which would prove that the matrix is not positive definite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x+y>\frac32$:

$$x^2+y^2=\frac12(x^2+y^2+x^2+y^2)\ge\frac12(x^2+y^2+2xy) =\frac12(x+y)^2>\frac98>1$$

Answer (score 1):

By direct definition:
A matrix $A$ is said to be positive definite if the scalar $u^TAu$ is strictly positive for every non-zero vectors $u$. Let $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$, $u_1,u_2,u_3\in \mathbb{R}$. Since $u$ is non-zero there must be a non-zero component, say $u_3\neq 0$ then we can divide by $u_3$ and without loss of generality assume directly that $u_3=1$ (you can check the case $u_3=0$ separately, you will see that the result is trivially positive). Then
$$u^T A u = \begin{pmatrix} u_1 & u_2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & x \\ 0 & 1 & y \\ x & y & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = u_1^2 + u_2^2 + 1 + 2xu_1 + 2y u_2.$$

Furthermore, observe that
$$u_1^2 + u_2^2 + 1 + 2xu_1 + 2y u_2 = (u_1+x)^2 + (u_2 +y)^2 -x^2 -y^2 +1.$$
In particular, the matrix is positive definite if
$$(u_1+x)^2 + (u_2 +y)^2 +1 > x^2 +y^2$$
which is implied by your condition.

Answer (score 0):

your matrix is symmetric real,

Use [Sylvester's Law of Inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia#Statement_in_terms_of_eigenvalues)

Congruence:

$$ 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1&0&0 \\
0&1&0 \\
-x&-y&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1&0&x\\
0&1&y \\
x&y&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1&0&-x \\
0&1&-y \\
0&0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1&0&0 \\
0&1&0 \\
0&0&1-x^2 - y^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The final diagonal matrix and your original are positive definite if and only if $x^2 + y^2 < 1$